# How to make some authors post in a blog

Tags: python, django

Good afternoon! Now I'm doing with something like a blog on django. But I do not understand how you can make it so that you can put not one author of the post, but two, three, four, etc. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that you have to use many to many relation.  Let your models be like ..

models.py

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    ....

class Blog(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=500)
    body = models.TextField()
    authors = models.ManyToManyField(Author, related_name="blogs")
    ...
```

Now if you have blog object, you will get all authors of the blog by calling `blog.authors.all()`. And if you have author object, you will get all blogs of the author by calling `author.blogs.all()`

Answer (score 1):

You are looking for a [Many To Many](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_many/) relationship.
Generally, it creates a third table used to link every ManyToMany relation between your two table. See [normalization](http://www.tomjewett.com/dbdesign/dbdesign.php?page=manymany.php). But when coding you don't care of the "real" implementation.

EDIT : on your case, you may just use 4 or 5 fields in the Article table and set them to null in case there aren't 5 authors. It depends on how many authors can write an Article.